# Any examples of getnextpage usage in the twilio api for c#?

Tags: c#, twilio

The old code I've inherited for Twilio retrieves messages using the absolute PageNumber property of the MessageListRequest but according to the documentation this is obsolete and I should be using GetNextPage and GetPrevPage.

The API metadata shows this as obsolete with the message "Use GetNextPage and GetPreviousPage for paging. Page parameter is scheduled for end of life https://www.twilio.com/engineering/2015/04/16/replacing-absolute-paging-with-relative-paging".

Are there any examples of this usage? I couldn't find any in the documentation except in one of the API test methods and I'm not sure how well I can get to processing multiple pages with this example as a guide.

```
public class Foo : TwilioBase
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FooResult : TwilioListBase
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
[Test]
public void ShouldGetNextPage()
{
    IRestRequest savedRequest = null;

    FooResult firstPage = new FooResult();
    firstPage.NextPageUri = new Uri("/Foos?PageToken=abc123", UriKind.Relative);

    mockClient.Setup(trc => trc.Execute<FooResult>(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
        .Callback<IRestRequest>((request) => savedRequest = request)
        .Returns(new FooResult());
    var client = mockClient.Object;

    var response = client.GetNextPage<FooResult>(firstPage);

    mockClient.Verify(trc => trc.Execute<FooResult>(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()), Times.Once);
    Assert.IsNotNull(savedRequest);
    Assert.AreEqual("/Foos?PageToken=abc123", savedRequest.Resource);
    Assert.AreEqual(Method.GET, savedRequest.Method);

    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
}
```

The old usage might look something like so:

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(config.AccountSid, config.AuthToken);
var result = new List<Message>();
MessageResult tempResult;
int page = 0;
do
{
    var request = new MessageListRequest();
    request = new MessageListRequest { Count = 1000, DateSent = newestDate, DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, PageNumber = page++, To = config.FromNumber };

    tempResult = twilio.ListMessages(request);
    result.AddRange(tempResult.Messages);
} while (tempResult.NextPageUri != null);
```

Finally, I built the Twilio API 3.4.1.0 from the [twilio-csharp GitHub project](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) instead of NuGet since I need to update it to use the MessagingServiceSid which isn't included in the API yet.

Thanks for any pointers. I'll post a solution if I can figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I got it to work now!

```
MessageResult messages = twilio.ListMessages(request);
do
{
    if (messages.Messages != null)
    {
        foreach (var message in messages.Messages) 
        {
            ... process results         
        }
        if (messages.NextPageUri != null)
        {
            messages = twilio.GetNextPage<MessageResult>(messages);
        }
    }
} while (messages.NextPageUri != null);
```

Comment: Won't this cause you to miss the last page of results? When you hit the last page, you call messages = twilio.GetNextPage, but then immediately hit the "while" clause. messages.NextPageUri no longer has the same value it did when you hit the if.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the example from the API Explorer?
https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/api-explorer/sms/sms-mms-list

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken); 

// Build the parameters 
var options = new MessageListRequest();    

var messages = twilio.ListMessages(options); 
foreach (var message in messages.Messages) 
{ 
 Console.WriteLine(message.Body); 
}
```

The [helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp) will automatically fetch from the API as you loop over the list until all records matching your criteria are processed.

You can limit the results with [MessageListRequest](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio.Api/Model/MessageListRequest.cs).

Please give that a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: That only returns a single page which has a maximum size of 1000 records. I need to retrieve all of the results. I'm using the now obsolete PageNumber MessageListRequest to page through the results until they are all retrieved.

Comment: ^^ This is not true, Paging must be used.