# Twilio GetNextPage to page through SMS logs

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I am attempting to retrieve all SMS logs from Twilio for the past 6 months and insert them into a table.  Last year Twilio deprecated absolute paging in favor of relative paging.  Any attempt to use `TwilioMessageListRequest.PageNumber`fails with a warning to use `GetNextPage and GetPreviousPage` instead.  However, I cannot find any documentation on their use.  The closest I've gotten to blindly piecing together is:

```
        var request = new MessageListRequest();
        var scheck = new TwilioListBase();
        scheck.PageSize = 1000;
        request.DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.GreaterThanOrEqualTo;
        request.DateSent = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(180));

        var messages = twilio.ListMessages(request);

        while(scheck.NextPageUri != null)
        {
            foreach (var message in messages.Messages)
            {
                string body = message.Body.ToString();

                SMS_Logs newLog = new SMS_Logs();
                newLog.Sid = message.Sid;
                newLog.DateSent = message.DateSent;
                newLog.To = message.To;
                newLog.From = message.From;
                newLog.Body = message.Body;
                newLog.Status = message.Status;
                newLog.ErrorCode = message.ErrorCode;
                newLog.ErrorMessage = message.ErrorMessage;

                db.SMS_Logs.InsertOnSubmit(newLog);
            }
            twilio.GetNextPage();
        }
```

This, however, cannot work.  As it stands, I receive the error "No overload for method 'GetNextPage' takes 0 arguments". I'm clearly missing a required component of `GetNextPage`, but I have been wildly unsuccessful in figuring out what that is thus far.  Any explanation of what I'm overlooking here would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552045/any-examples-of-getnextpage-usage-in-the-twilio-api-for-c/38088046#38088046

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of the following question: 
[Any examples of getnextpage usage in the twilio api for c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552045/any-examples-of-getnextpage-usage-in-the-twilio-api-for-c/38088046#38088046)

Give it a try from the API Explorer: https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/api-explorer/sms/sms-mms-list

The example in [C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp):

```
using System;
using Twilio;

class Example
{
    static void Main (string [] args)
    {

        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
        string AccountSid = "";
        string AuthToken = "";
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient (AccountSid, AuthToken);

        var request = new MessageListRequest ();

        var messages = twilio.ListMessages (request);

        while (messages.NextPageUri != null) {
            foreach (var message in messages.Messages) {
                Console.WriteLine (message.Body);
            }
            messages = twilio.GetNextPage<MessageResult> (messages);
        }
    }
}
```

The helper library will automatically fetch from the API as you loop over the list until all records matching your criteria are processed.

You can limit the results with MessageListRequest.

Comment: Could you expound on this a bit?  The API Explorer only allows the user to set parameters for From #, To #, and Date Sent. In addition, it provides the same results as what I have above--the 50 most recent records if no Date Sent is specified or the last 50 records of the Date Sent. How can I loop through the list if not by `GetNextPage`?  I don't see any method of doing so from within the API Explorer.

Comment: Hi! I've expanded the code snippet a bit to show using `GetNextPage` to get multiple pages of results. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: `messages = twilio.GetNextPage<MessageResult> (messages)` was precisely what I was missing, worked perfectly.  Thanks!!